# Problema with a view on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view on my app where i use the command render like this

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Fecha Creacion</th>
                <th>Prioridad</th>
                <th>Fecha Limite</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%= render :file => "/notes/_pendientes.html.erb" %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

But when i'm going to see the index at the beginning of the app this look like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUTGT.jpg

and in the controller I have the variables like this

@pendientes     = Note.where('estado = ?',true)
@finalizadas    = Note.where('estado = ?',false)

I dont know why is showing that information at the beginning of the index

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `/notes/_pendientes.html.erb` file (which you didn't show), there's a Rails coding error. I'm thinking you likely have a `<%= ... %>` on something you should only have `<% ... %>` for. You only want `<%= ... %>` if you want to display the output of the enclosed ruby code. If you're doing something like a form:

```
<% @foos.each do |foo| %>
 ... some HTML and interleaved erb stuff here ...
<% end %>
```

You do not want the `=` on the first statement (NOT `<%= @foos.each do |foo| %>`).

Also, your line:

```
<%= render :file => "/notes/_pendientes.html.erb" %>
```

I thought would be more appropriate as:

```
<%= render :partial => "/notes/pendientes" %>
```

But that doesn't seem to be causing a problem.

Comment: jajajajajajajajaj the reason was just a =
thank you so much :D

Comment: if you parent view is in the `notes` folder you could do `render 'pendientes'`